# how to set a path to the local directory in c# for .mdf database in Service.cs file

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, filepath

Do you know how to set a path to the local directory in c# when trying to set a path for a datbase in the service.cs file? (I am developing in VS2010)

I have developed a winforms program that uses a `.mdf` (SQL Server) database. The program communicates to the database through a SQL Server connection string.

I have hard coded the path of the db at the mo but would like to know how to point to the current directory.

I have seen online

```
AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me as the connection will not open.

Also I have tried using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` however that with `CurrentDirectory` is weirdly not in the namespace.

Comment: The `AttachDbFileName=` approach **only** works with SQL Server **EXPRESS** edition - not with any of the other editions.

Comment: Show the line of code and the *exact* error message you get when trying to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Also, try `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: I am using express. 'AttachDbFileName=' with an absolute path works fine. The application is to be packaged into an installer and distributed.

Comment: Environment is recognised as a class, adding the dot doesnt show up any methods or options.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same assembly folder you can use this

```
    string folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myCS"].ConnectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myCS"].ConnectionString.Replace("#folder#",folder);

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
```

Comment: can i use that variable to make a connection string? not so sure.

Comment: @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=folder;Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";

Comment: Add a placeholder in the connectionstring (like #folder#) and make a string.Replace("#folder#",folder) from code

Comment: Nice. Will check when i have access to my dev machine. Will give feedback when i know result.

Comment: Errors: 'Service.config' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: In the end decided to force the directory that the db would be installed to in using the vs installer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to solution Explorer >> right click the project>> click properties>> go to setting tab>>Make name: MyConnectionString Type:(connection string) Scoper: Application

and select the DB(Db should be kept in your |DataDirectory| along with your dblog)>> select that DB. >> save it.

Then use this code for connection
 SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString);

**You have to give the namespace: using System.Data.SqlServerCe;**

hope this will solve.

Accept if this works and close the question

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to get the .mdf and .ldf of a databese, through the code that have worked for me, to do that, **open a connection** to the database using the connection string, **prepare SQL command**, with the query

```
select physical_name from sys.database_files where type = 0
```

**then execute the command**, and by the way, `type = 0`, is for mdf, and `type = 1` is for ldf, you can also use this query directly in the SSMS

this is the sample code, keep in mind that you need to get the connection string

```
        string _mdfCommand = "select physical_name from sys.database_files where type = 0";
        string _ldfCommand = "select physical_name from sys.database_files where type = 1";

        SqlCommand GetSQLData = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        GetSQLData.CommandText = _mdfCommand;

        GetSQLData.Connection = connection;
        string mdf_Path= (string)GetSQLData.ExecuteScalar();

        GetSQLData.CommandText = _ldfCommand;
        GetSQLData.Connection = connection;
        string ldf_Path= (string)GetSQLData.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
```